# Как сделать запрос с subquery sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlalchemy

Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать данный запрос в sqlalchemy?

```
select * from vouchers 
where "closed" not in (select orders.status from orders 
                       where orders.voucher_id = vouchers.id);
```

Примеры моделей в sqlalchemy

```
class Voucher(Base):
    __tablename__ = "vouchers"
    
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    orders = relationship ("Order")


class Order (Base):
    __tablename__ = "orders"

    id = Column (BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    voucher_id = Column (BigInteger, ForeignKey("vouchers.id")
    voucher = relationship (Voucher)
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему запросу, вы хотите получить все ваучеры статус которых в заказе не равен "closed".

Я бы посоветовал вам сделать это с помощью join. Если все ForeignKey настроены правильно и сущности имеют только одно отношение друг с другом, то вам даже не нужно указывать по каким полям объединять таблицы.

Тогда вам запрос можно написать в sqlalchemy так:

```py
sa_session.query(Voucher).join(Order).filter(Order.status != 'closed').all()
```

или так, указав поля для связи:

```py
sa_session.query(Voucher).join(Order, Order.voucher_id == Voucher.id).filter(Order.status != 'closed').all()
```